# Why are the basis elements of $T_pM$ a vector field if we let $p$ vary?

Tags: differential-topology

At the end of this [article on tangent vectors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ManifoldTangentVector.html), they say each $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ is a vector field, if we let the point $p$ vary. However, they are only defined in a particular coordinate chart.

I know that $\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \mid_p \}$ is a basis for $T_pM.$

However, I also know that vector fields are sections of the bundle $TM$. How can $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ be a vector field if its domain is not all of $M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article you linked to:

> "Letting the base point vary in the coordinate chart, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ are vector fields, but are only defined in this coordinate chart."

The $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ are vector fields on the domain of the coordinate chart, they are not vector fields on the whole manifold. That is, they are maps $U \to TU \cong \pi^{-1}(U)$ where $\pi : TM \to M$ is the natural projection, and $U$ is the domain of the coordinate chart $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

Comment: Here, $TU \cong U \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is one of the local trivialization of the vector bundle right?

Comment: That is correct.